# Python background script to retrieve emails from Microsoft OAUTH2

Tags: python-3.x, microsoft-graph-api

I have a background script that is constantly querying the email to see if there is any new email and do some magic stuff with is content/attachments.
This using IMAP but the email account that I am using is being migrated to office365 and due to policies it will be shutdown and I need to migrate the scripts to start use Graph and AUTH2.

And here comes the problem. The Administrator as provided me a test account to test access and connections.

They have provide me the following information:
Display name: xxxxxxxxxxx
Application (client) ID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Directory (tenant) ID: xxxxxxxx
Secret: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Shared Mailbox: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Functional Account: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Pass: xxxxxxxxxxxx

Endpoints for Authorization and Token:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/authorize
https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token

When I open the endpoints given (directly on the browser to check connectivity) I have the following errors
Authorize: *AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_id'.*

Token: *AADSTS900561: The endpoint only accepts POST, OPTIONS requests. Received a GET request.*

And I have prepared a script test like this:

```
import msal
import requests

# Define the Azure OAuth 2.0 SSO endpoint URLs
TENANT_ID = ''
AUTHORITY_URL = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + TENANT_ID + "/oauth2/authorize"
CLIENT_ID = ''
CLIENT_SECRET = ''

# Define the Azure Graph API endpoint URLs
GRAPH_API_URL = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0'
EMAILS_ENDPOINT = GRAPH_API_URL + '/me/messages'


def save_attachment(attachment_url, headers, file_path):
    attachment_response = requests.get(attachment_url, headers=headers)
    if attachment_response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
        with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(attachment_response.content)
        print(f'Saved attachment to {file_path}')
    else:
        print(f'Failed to retrieve attachment. Status code: {attachment_response.status_code}')


# Create a `ConfidentialClientApplication` instance to authenticate the user
app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    CLIENT_ID,
    client_credential=CLIENT_SECRET,
    authority=AUTHORITY_URL
)
# Obtain an access token using the `acquire_token_for_client` method
# result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=[GRAPH_API_URL + '/.default'], proxies=proxy_options)
result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=[GRAPH_API_URL + '/.default'])

# Check if the access token was obtained successfully
if "access_token" in result:
    # Call the Azure Graph API to retrieve emails using the `requests` library with the appropriate headers and proxy
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token']
    }
    # response = requests.get(EMAILS_ENDPOINT, headers=headers)
    response = requests.get(EMAILS_ENDPOINT, headers=headers)

    # Parse the response and print the subject lines of the emails
    if response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
        emails = response.json()['value']
        count = 0
        for email in emails:
            print('Subject:', email['subject'])

            # Retrieve attachments if they exist
            if 'attachments' in email:
                for attachment in email['attachments']:
                    # Call the Azure Graph API to retrieve the attachment content
                    attachment_id = attachment['id']
                    attachment_url = f"{EMAILS_ENDPOINT}/{email['id']}/attachments/{attachment_id}"
                    attachment_name = attachment['name']

                    # Define a file path to save the attachment
                    file_path = f"{attachment_name}"

                    # Save the attachment to the local file system
                    save_attachment(attachment_url, headers, file_path)

            else:
                print('No attachments found.')
            count += 1
            if count >= 5:
                break
    else:
        print('Failed to retrieve emails. Status code:', response.status_code)
else:
    print(result.get("error_description"))
```

With this particular code the error is this:
*requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='login.microsoftonline.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /*********/oauth2/authorize/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001DAB297C880>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))*

I know that in this particular case *ConfidentialClientApplication* is adding the /v2.0/ automatically but I have try other solutions (chatGPT had try give me other solutions but always the ConnectionError

It seems I can never pass the token/authentic URL request.

I am stuck on this for a couple of days.

Thank you advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Authority parameter you passing is incorrect eg

```
AUTHORITY_URL = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + TENANT_ID + "/oauth2/authorize"
```

should just be

```
AUTHORITY_URL = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + TENANT_ID
```

MSAL does an oidc discovery https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc which will then return the correct token endpoint. What happening for you is the oidc endpoint is being appended to you incorrect AUTHORITY_URL which is why you see the /********/oauth2/authorize/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration error

Comment: Thanks ;) apart from that error there was another issue due to network limitations due to the proxy ahahahah..